# using a wildcard when merging two dataframes in python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have the following code to take a requested list of parts from clipboard, **request**, and merge with a dataframe of recalled parts, **db**, resulting in a dataframe **res** of recalls associated with the requested parts list.

I want to change this code to be able to merge the two dataframes with a wildcard added to the requested list of parts (ex: **03.5** would merge to **03.501**, **03.524**, etc. in **db**).

I tried adding a asterisk with `request['PARTS'] = request['PARTS'].str.upper() + "*"` but it did not work. 
Thank you for your time.

```
import pandas as pd

#load recalled parts database
db = pd.read_csv(r'resources/recall_part_db.csv', sep=';',converters={'PARTS':str})
db['PARTS'] = db['PARTS'].str.upper()

#import search request from clipboard (excel)
request = pd.read_clipboard(names=['PARTS'], sep='\r\n',converters={'PARTS':str})
request['PARTS'] = request['PARTS'].str.upper()

res = pd.merge(db,request, on=['PARTS','PARTS'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`request['PARTS'] = request['PARTS'].str.upper() + "*"` should work actually.

Try this way :

```
request['PARTS'] = request['PARTS'].apply(lambda s: s.upper() + "*")
```

Comment: I tried this and it does add the `*`, but it does not merge properly: ex: 530.5* does not merge with 530.521 and 530.522 in the recalled parts dataframe, db

Comment: could you explain more in details what is this merging part and how you perform it ? it's quite unclear

Comment: I edited the code in the question to remove lines unrelated to the question.  I am trying to inner join (pandas.merge) a dataframe of parts, to a dataframe of recalled parts.  But I want to merge with a wildcard at the end of each row of the request dataframe.